# Subset df by last valid item - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subset a df using a last specific value. Using below, I want to subset every row before the time `X` appears in `Item`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({              
    'Item' : ['Y','X','B','X','A','Y'], 
    'Number' : [2,3,2,4,2,1],                          
    })

df_out = df[df['Item'] == 'X'].last_valid_index()
```

Intended output:

```
  Item  Number
0    Y       2
1    X       3
2    B       2
3    X       4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `iloc`:

```
a = df[df['Item'] == 'X'].last_valid_index()
print(df.iloc[:a + 1])
```

Output:

```
  Item  Number
0    Y       2
1    X       3
2    B       2
3    X       4
```